# Brute force feature selection - sum items across list combinations

Tags: python, for-loop, combinations

I have x lists of parameters & a list containing a list of the x lists. A total score is calculated by summing each corresponding item in each list.

For example, I have 2 lists & a main list like so:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [2,1]
mainList = ['a','b']
```

I want all the unique combinations - this is given by:

```
for L in range(0, len(mainList)+1):
for subset in itertools.combinations(mainList, L):
    print(subset)
```

Output:

```
()
('a',)
('b',)
('a', 'b')
```

For each permutation, I wish to create a new list containing the overall score by summing the items of each included list.

So for example, in this case the desired outputs would be:

```
[0,0] 
[1,2] #i.e. just a
[2,1] #i.e. just b
[3,3] #i.e. a+b
```

This is where I'm stuck - I'm not sure how to get the desired output above.

I suspect I'm overcomplicating it & there's just a quick way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip(*...)` to 'transpose' the lists (e.g. convert `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` to `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`) and then sum the elements:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
main = [a, b]  # make main a list of the lists rather than text labels

for length in range(len(main)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(main, length):
        result = [sum(t) for t in zip(*subset)]
        if result:
            print(result)
        else:
            print([0] * len(main[0]))
```

Note however that the first sum (sum of no lists) is `[]` so we need a specific line to replace that.

If you need to keep the labels `'a', 'b'` then make `main` a dictionary:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
main = {'a': a, 'b': b}
list_length = len(list(main.values())[0])
for length in range(len(main)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(main, length):
        if subset:
            print(subset, [sum(t) for t in zip(*[main[key] for key in subset])])
        else:
            print(subset, [0] * list_length)
```

Alternatively, and perhaps simpler, use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
main = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4]})
for length in range(len(main)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(main, length):
        print(subset, main[list(subset)].sum(axis=1).to_list())
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it still possible for me to get the parameters in each iteration? I can get the number using `print(len(subset))`, but can't figure out how to work out what the actual parameters are (e.g. in this iteration the parameters are `a` & `b`)

Comment: See edits - using a pandas dataframe is usually the easier way to work with labeled columns of data.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to somehow connect a & b strings with corresponding lists. I think the cleanest way is to have a dictionary containing lists' names and lists with their values.

Here is an example:

```
list_dict = {'a': a, 'b': b}

for L in range(0, len(mainList)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(mainList, L):
        temp = [0, 0]
        for sub in subset:
            temp[0] += list_dict[sub][0]
            temp[1] += list_dict[sub][1]
        print(temp)
```